# Extra spacing after an A Tag/img tag?

Tags: html, css, tags, image, space

Hello i'm trying to build a table cell using div tag and while doing so. i get this extra spacing after my img a tag within the cell.

```
<div display:table>
 <div display:row>
  <div display:tabel-cell>
   <a><img/></a>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of that extra spacing.

i tried display:inline for the a and img tag. yet not luck.

if anyone can help me get rid of this spacing i would gladly appreciate it.

Example -- right before the shadowing there a 2-3 pixel white space within this tabel-cell

[image: http://i.imgur.com/DLPWH.png]

Comment: I love reading textual explanations of HTML code. It's much better than reading the HTML code itself...

Comment: sorry next time i'll add it in. i edited it. though

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Aside from the fact that you should use tables for tabular data, I think that setting `display: block` on the image will remove the space. If that doesn' work, try to make a jsFiddle page to show off the problem.

Comment: Hey thanks it worked. i totally forgot about block. I was thinking of using tables but dont know if there a difference.

Comment: Yeah, hear you about "tables for data", but you try telling that to almost every email client out there when you're coding an email that you'd like to display reasonably nicely on most platforms...

Answer (score 2):

That space can be removed using:

```
style="display:block;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `margin: 0` and `padding: 0` on the elements that have this extra spacing. It is usually a good idea to implement some sort of [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to make sure all elements are cleared of these annoying default attributes such as margins and padding.