# table-cell > img extra 4px space

Tags: html, css, image, css-tables

The question is similar to this one: 
[Extra spacing after an A Tag/img tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733264/extra-spacing-after-an-a-tag-img-tag)
But the solution was to apply display:block to the image but if I do it, my vertical-align is lost.

```
<div class="main" style="display:table;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;">
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf34P/
img height: 32px, parent div height: 36px. Can't find a way to remove it and keep `vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;` so the image is centered. These 4 pixels are really annoying when the image height is set to window's height via JavaScript so scrollbar appears. Any ideas how to remove it? Thanks.

Comment: If you are ok to use margin:auto instead of text-align:center. The display:flex should make the deal. http://jsfiddle.net/LG68Q/

Comment: not working, also it was deprecated wasn't it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LG68Q/2/ use ```display:block``` with ```margin: 0 auto``` to center the img.

Comment: @Eich but I also need vertical-align: middle; for the parent div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set your image to a block element you have to center it as a block element with `margin: 0 auto`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LG68Q/2/

@Yoann's solution also works, but the `flex` value is not supported by every browser. Have a look at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) for more information about browser support and values of `display`.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't work with vertical align of parent set to middle but it does. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok to use margin:auto instead of text-align:center. The display:flex should make the deal.

```
display:flex
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LG68Q

Comment: for example IE < 10 does not support it does it

Comment: No worries, his answer is much better!